# Django Password Decrypt in PHP (with salt and cypher)

Tags: php, django, encryption, password-encryption

in Django we save a hashed password cypher like

```
"gAAAAABgiwEaPluFLV48a1kZFLIQDJfvk5elLjRGBAwuLVwnkhzpOtxLTU4n6ble1pB0DNCYdDdcU1MaGL3uFAQvwILVJNx50w=="
```

and a salt like

```
"-GcGi6r3TmMNz5cD8Cagpfli3Es-hz_s3hda5vr5G60="
```

in Python i decrypt password with [Fernet Library](https://github.com/heroku/fernet-py) like

```
f = Fernet(salt)
password = f.decrypt(bytes(password_cypher.encode())).decode()
```

and question is how Decrypt like this method in php...? (Laravel & PHP)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php That said, PBKDF isn't particularly great for password storage, if you were to switch to a more broadly-implemented method that is intended for passwords, eg: bcrypt, you would be able to leverage PHP's builtins: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

Comment: thanks, i know that bro, and everywhere i use bcrypt to store password in db, but this is a programm writed in django and now i must show a bunch of passwords for... so i must use cypher and salt for show that, in django it's ok, and php too. i solved that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php i used library

```
kelvinmo/fernet-php
```

and code is simple too

```
$fernet = new \Fernet\Fernet(salt);
echo $fernet->decode(password_cypher)
```